# Pushing array from forEach and passing to res

Tags: javascript, callback, sails.js

I'm new to both javascript and sails. I'm a bit confused with javascript's callback. Right now my controller has this method:

```
test: function(req, res) {
  var arr = [], someId = [15,16,7];
  someId.forEach(function(val, idx) {
    var temp = {};
    User.find({userId: val}).exec(function(err, usr) {
      Profile.find({profileId: usr.profId}).exec(function(err, prof) {
        temp.name = prof.fullName();
        temp.email = usr.email;
        ...
        arr.push(temp);
        res.json(arr);
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Everything is going smooth but the json response only sends the first value not the last, so I am assuming that the res.json passes only the first `arr.push` during the callback execution. How and where do I call the `res.json` so that it will only execute only when the callback is done. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your queries by using Waterline's built-in "in"-query syntax: if you set a criteria value to an array, it will search for all records whose value for that field match one from the array.  So:

```
// Find all users whose ID is in the someId array
User.find({userId: someId}).exec(function(err, users) {

    if (err) {return res.serverError(err);

    // Get the profile IDs of those users using Lodash "pluck"
    var profileIds = _.pluck(users, 'profId');

    // Find all Profile records with those IDs
    Profile.find({profileId: profileIds}).exec(function(err, profiles) {

        if (err) {return res.serverError(err);

        // Use Array.map to transform the profiles array data
        var results = profiles.map(function(profile) {
            // Use Lodash to get the user with this profile ID
            var user = _.find(users, {profId: profile.profileId});
            return {name: profile.fullName(), email: user.email};
        });
        return res.json(results);

    });


});
```

Note that `_` (Lodash) is globalized by Sails by default, so you can use it in any of your controllers, models or services.

An alternative would be to use the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) (also globalized by Sails) to re-organize the code in a more linear fashion, rather than using nested callbacks.

If you're using Sails v0.10.x, you might also consider using [associations](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models/Associations) to relate the User and Profile records directly; then you'd be able to just do:

```
User.find({userId: someId}).populate('profile').exec(...);
```

to get everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until all the callbacks are done. An easy way to do this is: each time the `Profile.find` callback runs, check if this is the final one by checking the length of `arr`.

```
someId.forEach(function(val, idx) {
    User.find({userId: val}).exec(function(err, usr) {
      Profile.find({profileId: usr.profId}).exec(function(err, prof) {
        var temp = {};
        temp.name = prof.fullName();
        temp.email = usr.email;
        ...
        arr.push(temp);

         // if arr is now full, send it; otherwise, wait for more
        if(arr.length == someId.length) { res.json(arr); }
      })
    })
})
```

However, you say that you don't know how long the "finished" array is until you query `Users`. The solution here is to query *all* the users first, and then query profiles after:

```
var usersProcessedCount = 0, matchedUsers = [];
someId.forEach(function(val, idx) {
    User.find({userId: val, status: 1}).exec(function(err, usr) {
      if(usr != null) { matchedUsers.push(usr); }
      if(++usersProcessedCount == someId.length) { fetchProfiles(); }
    })
})

function fetchProfiles() {
    matchedUsers.forEach(val, idx) {
      Profile.find({profileId: val.profId}).exec(function(err, prof) {
        var temp = {};
        temp.name = prof.fullName();
        temp.email = val.email;
        ...
        arr.push(temp);

         // if arr is now full, send it; otherwise, wait for more
        if(arr.length == matchedUsers.length) { res.json(arr); }
      })
    });
}
```

Here we store all the users that meet the criteria in an array, and then, when we finished processing all the candidate IDs, we call `fetchProfiles`, which loops over the list of matched users.

Comment: I've already tried this, it works fine but the problem here is that what if you put some constraints when querying the user. E.g. `User.find({userId: val}).where({'status': 1})` the usr length won't match the length of the arr. Is there another work around for this?

Comment: @mateeyow Edited to address your concerns about filtering: build an array of filtered uers and then perform the fetch of profiles based on that filtered list (and use the length of that list to determine when you've finished).

Comment: I don't think it will work since usersProcessedCount will increment only upto the length of the usr and since not all user has the status 1 the `if(++usersProcessedCount == someId.length)` will not be true

Comment: @mateeyow Maybe I misunderstamd how Sails handles empty results. I assumed that requests that don't find a match (i.e., the record's status is not 1) will run the callback with a `null` value for `usr`; thus, `usetsProcessedCount` will increment on both matching and non-matching queries. Are you suggesting that for non-matching records, the callback will not run *at all*? That seems wrong, since you can't distinguish between a no-results request and a very slow request.

Answer (score -1):

```
test: function(req, res) {
  var arr = [], someId = [15,16,7];
  someId.forEach(function(val, idx) {
    var temp = {};
    User.find({userId: val}).exec(function(err, usr) {
      Profile.find({profileId: usr.profId}).exec(function(err, prof) {
        temp.name = prof.fullName();
        temp.email = usr.email;
        ...
        arr.push(temp);
      })
    })
  })
  res.json(arr);
}
```

You did not reach the end of the loop. You already passed the value of "ARR" after finishing the first item

Comment: A model's `exec` method is asynchrous, so this code sends `arr` before *any* of the callbacks have run. Your code launches all the requests, but it does not wait for the `exec` callbacks to run; thus, it sends back `arr` before it has been populated with any data.